# Issue when installing node-sass

Tags: node.js, node-sass

I get an issue when installing `node-sass` :

```
gyp verb download contents checksum {"node-v10.2.1-headers.tar.gz":"3700814861e61288d7dd1c4115f40acac0cbd0abbdd4bfd650d4ae85cc02ecce"}
gyp verb validating download checksum for node-v10.2.1-headers.tar.gz (3700814861e61288d7dd1c4115f40acac0cbd0abbdd4bfd650d4ae85cc02ecce == 3700814861e61288d7dd1c4115f40acac0cbd0abbdd4bfd650d4ae85cc02ecce)
gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 10.2.1
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /var/www/****/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/****/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-116-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/var/www/****/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/****/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v10.2.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN gestiaweb@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/****/.npm/_logs/2018-06-01T14_24_13_534Z-debug.log
```

**Environment :** Ubuntu (lastest)

**NodeJS version :** v10.2.1

**Npm version :** 5.6.0

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a permissions issue. Can you install other packages?

If not make sure the user you are running the npm i node-gyp command has permissions to write to the appropriate directory.

```
chmod +w <path>/node_modules
```

In this case there seemed to be a permission issue with the user's node install

Solution:

```
sudo su && npm i node-sass
```

Comment: Yes the other packages are well installed without any errors. But with `node-sass` I get this error : `errno: -13, syscall: 'mkdir',code: 'EACCES',path: '/var/www/***/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'`.

Comment: @tonymx227 is there already a node_modules/node-sass directory or a node_modules/node-gyp ?

Comment: @tonymx227 also are you running "sudo npm i node-sass" from the root project directory or do you have other flags? maybe try "npm cache verify"

Comment: Yes I have a `node_modules/node-sass` directory and a `node_modules/node-gyp` directory too. It seems to be an issue with the vendor of `node-sass`...

Comment: try removing both of those directories and reinstalling. Maybe even install node-gyp globally first

Comment: When using `sudo npm uninstall node-sass` and `sudo npm uninstall node-gyp` I get an error...

Comment: Update : When using `sudo su` and `npm install node-sass` it works... Why ?

Comment: @tonymx227 that is curious.. the first way of doing it basically runs the command as you but with root privileges whereas changing to root, you are that user.

Comment: @tonymx227 if you don't mind giving me an upvote or an accepted answer i'd appreciate it...i'm trying to get the comment privileges on stackoverflow and I've just been a "long time listener, first time caller"

Answer (score 0):

```
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied,
```

Its says permission denied. Try run with sudo

```
sudo npm i node-sass
```

Comment: I'm using "sudo" to install my packages... So this not the issue.